# Arcpy Append doesn't work with tables

Tags: arcpy, append

I am trying to get data from table A to table B. But it is important that domains in table B would remain. So I tried to use Append, but it doesn't work with tables. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you getting an error message when you are trying to use append?

Comment: Can you share your code?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps use  **[arcpy.SearchCursor](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000v00000039000000)** to iterate through Table A and use  **[arcpy.InsertCursor](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/InsertCursor/000v00000038000000/)** to insert the values selected in **Table A** into **Table B**, you can even use **[arcpy.UpdateCursor](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/UpdateCursor/000v0000003m000000/)** to update existing fields.

Unfortunately I don't know what your data looks like so I am unable to give you an example of each tool that replicates your scenario., but, I hope these tools give you what you are looking for.

if you are looking to actually create **Table B** from **Table A** you can use **[arcpy.CopyRows_management(dbaseTable, outTable)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//0017000000n4000000)**

Comment: I use these tools all the time to select & query data from tables and insert values into other tables etc.